# Populate Tableview with super class fields

Tags: javafx, java-8, callback, tableview

I have several classes that all inherit from one `super` class that need to populate several `TableView`s related to their class.

The super class is abstract and some of the getters and setters are final but still contains data needed to populate the cells.

Writing a new Callback class for each and every column is doable, but I'm looking for a way to implements this.

#### sample code

```java
class SuperClass
{
  protected String name;
  protected double value;
  public final void setName(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public final void getName()
  {
    return this.name;
  }
  public final void setValue(double value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public double getValue()
  {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

```java
class SubClass1 extends SuperClass
{
  private int id;
  public void setId(int id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public int getId()
  {
    return this.id;
  }
}
```

```java
class SubClass2 extends SuperClass
{
  private String location;
  public void setLocation(String location)
  {
    this.location = location;
  }
}
```

```java
class SubClass3 extends SuperClass
{
  private ObservableMap<SuperClass> map;
  public ObservableMap<SuperClass> map()
  {
    return this.map;
  }
}
```

#### TableView

```java
TableColumn<SubClass1, Integer> tc1_id;
TableColumn<SubClass1, String> tc1_name;
TableColumn<SubClass1, Double> tc1_value;
TableColumn<SubClass2, String> tc2_loc;
TableColumn<SubClass2, String> tc2_name;
TableColumn<SubClass2, Double> tc2_value;
TableColumn<SubClass3, String> tc3_name;
TableColumn<SubClass3, Double> tc3_value;
```

Here's a reference of what I was going to do...
[Accessing Subclass properties in a JavaFX TableView ObservableArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134394/accessing-subclass-properties-in-a-javafx-tableview-observablearraylist)

But just with the sample code, I'm basically rewriting 2 methods, 3 times each... and there's a bit more than that in the actual program. (Just a smidge more)

Comment: You can't use all those columns in the same `TableView`. A `TableColumn<S,T>` can only be added to a `TableView<S>`, so the first type parameter must be the same for all your columns.

Comment: tc1 refers to table 1 -> column X
tc2 refers to table 2 -> column X
tc3 refers to table 3 -> column X

Comment: So each subclass corresponds to a different table? In that case, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: That is correct. "several TableView"

Comment: So, what are you asking?

Comment: A way to not have to write out 60+ anonymous `CallBack` classes for each `TableView` for each column that has their properties derived from the `SuperClass`

Comment: Just write a single function to set the `cellValueFactory` on a table column, and call it for each column. `Callback` is a `FunctionalInterface`, so you can reduce code further by using lambdas. Is there a reason you're not using JavaFX Properties in your classes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216166/discussion-between-david-fisher-and-james-d).

Comment: explain your problem here (best with a [mcve]) and java naming conventions please .. Note that this site is _not_ a helpdesk, but a community effort to build a knowledge base, incomplete/vague/unclear questions don't help in that effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just asking how to reduce the amount of code you have to write. The solution is just the same as any such question: write a method that performs the repetitive part, and parametrize it with the parts that vary. So in this case, you just need to write a generic utility method to generate your table columns, taking the title of the column and the function that produces the property the cell value factory needs.

E.g. you could do something like

```
private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> createColumn(String title, Function<S, Property<T>> prop) {
    TableColumn<S,T> column = new TableColumn<>(title);
    column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> prop.apply(cellData.getValue()));
    return column ;
}
```

and then if your model classes use JavaFX properties, all you need is

```
TableColumn<SubClass1, Number> tc1Id = createColumn("Id", SubClass1::idProperty);
```

etc.

If you are not using JavaFX properties (which is the recommended approach), you can still do

```
TableColumn<SubClass2, String> tc2Loc = 
    createColumn("Location", item -> new SimpleStringProperty(item.getLocation()));
```

or just create a method that accepts a `Function<S,T>` instead of a `Function<S,Property<T>>`.

Comment: After converting SuperClass's fields to Property type and adding in the methods StringProperty nameProperty(), I still have an issue with `TableView<SuperClass> table; TableColumn<SuperClass, StringProperty> tableColumn = createColumn("Name", SuperClass::nameProperty); table.setItems(ObservableList<SuperClass>);` though I know in your first answer you mentioned something about not being able to have multiple types of items in a `TableView` but the `TableColumn`s are only referencing `Properties` from the `SuperClass`

Comment: What is the issue, specifically?

Comment: `tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(PropertyValueFactory<SuperClass, StringProperty>("name");` generates TableColumn cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellDataFeatures
---
`TableColumn<SuperClass, StringProperty> tableColumn = createColumn("name", SuperClass::nameProperty);` won't compile " incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)"
 --- 
signature for `SuperClass::nameProperty` is `public final StringProperty nameProperty()`

Comment: @DavidFisher Yes, because it should be `TableColumn<SuperClass, String> tableColumn = createColumn(...);`. For a `TableColumn<S,T>` the method signature is `setCellValueFactory(Callback<CellDataFeatures<S,T>, ObservableValue<T>>)`. So if you make `T` a `StringProperty` you'd end up having to return an `ObservableValue<StringProperty>`, instead of what is currently returned (a `StringProperty`, which implements `ObservableValue<String>`).

Comment: Seems weird that I can't have a `T extend Property` But I guess that works

Comment: @DavidFisher why? The cell value factory has to return an observable wrapper of the value of the cell (so that it can automatically update). Why would you want the actual value displayed to be an observable wrapper of something? It's not exactly natural to have `StringProperty` as a property type (so your bean methods would be `public StringProperty getName();` `public void setName(StringProperty value);` and `public Property<StringProperty> nameProperty()` ???).